# renaming custom libraries in python

Tags: python, jenkins

> I created a custom library in python and I published it using jenkins, my problem is that to call my new library I would use `

```
import lib.my_lib
```

but I want to change so I use

```
import my_lib
```

directly. I want to find a solution where I can change this in my code and from my research I think it should be in the **init** file but I don't know how to do it.

I tried to initialize the library by using from lib.my_lib import my_lib hoping that would make my_lib recognizable but it didn't work.

This is my project structure:

```
lib
|__docs
|_my_lib
|___
    |_model
    |_my_lib.py
    |___init__.py
|_tests
|_setup.py
|_requirements.txt
|_jenkinsfile
```

Comment: Is there a place where we can see your code (e.g. github) or can you give us some more information about the structure of your project?

Comment: Perhaps see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/9731347).

Comment: That answer doesn't fix my problem because I want users to call directly my custom library but its name my_lib without having to deal with paths

Comment: Well, either you use `sys` to add the `lib` folder to the `PATH` or you use `import lib.my_lib` (which is the best way). Those are the only ways to import a file that is in a subfolder. I also am confused about what kind of benefit you're trying to achieve. Saving you from typing four characters?